# nginfiniteScroll appears to block controller

Tags: angularjs, nginfinitescroll

If I comment out...

> ```
> infinite-scroll="content.loadContent()
> ```

... then my items bind correctly. If I leave it in then, even though `loadContent` is called when I scroll, no items are bound.

```
div(ng-controller='contentController as content', class="wrapper", ng-cloak)
    ul#contentList(infinite-scroll="content.loadContent()", infinite-scroll-distance="20")
        li.item(ng-repeat='item in content.content')
            OMG
```

If I bind to a simple inline array then that binds ok even with infinite scroll in place.

Why is infinite scroll stopping my controller content from binding? Is it because it has an isolate scope? If so then how does the demo code [here](http://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/demo_basic.html) manage to access the scope of the outer controller?

Comment: plunkr might be useful here, you are giving us quite limited info

Comment: @IanWarburton found any solution? i'm having same issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37511169/angular-binding-not-working-properly-with-nginfinitescroll

Comment: @adolfosrs I switched to server side rendering for my site for SEO.

Comment: @IanWarburton dont know if i got it. How can i do this?

Comment: @adolfosrs Sorry, what I meant was that I stopped using Angular. I didn't find a solution to this problem.